# Powershell - how to run a script located on another computer?

Tags: powershell

Could anyone please offer me some hints? I am stuck with this problem.

I have developed a PowerShell script located in:

```
\\\ComputerNameA.xxx.xxx.local\d\xxx\script.ps1
```

This script requires 4 arguments to work. I need to run that script from another computer.

I have tried:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ComputerNameA 
      -FilePath \\\ComputerNameA.xxx.xxx.local\d\xxx\script.ps1  
      -ArgumentList {-arg0 string -arg1 string -arg2 string -arg3 string}
```

Any hints will be appreciated.

Update:
As to answer my original question, I think the answer is:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ComputerNameA -Credential $cred
-FilePath \\ComputerNameA.xxx.xxx.local\d\xxx\script.ps1
-ArgumentList {-arg0 string -arg1 string -arg2 string -arg3 string}

Now, the new problem is I got the access denied error even the credential is exist (i.e. I setup a new user account - abcd and set the password as abcd)

Comment: What's the error when you ran the script from another system

Comment: Thank you Jawad. I fixed the previous problem. I need to use " " for a folder name which contains a space. The new error message is: connecting to remote server ComputerNameA failed with the following error message: access is denied.

Comment: Your invoke command needs credentials to access the other computer. You either need domain level access to run it, or use pssession to set credentials and then use them. or you can set them in the command with username parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7

Comment: Thank you Robert. I setup a new user account in ComputerNameA, make the user be member of "Users" and "PS Job Users". And also use -credential in invoke-command, but still failed with: AccessDenied, PSSessionStateBroken

Answer (score 0):

If you try to execute a PS1 script located on a remote computer as if you do it physically on the computer itself, then you can achieve this via Remote Powershell.

https://4sysops.com/archives/use-powershell-invoke-command-to-run-scripts-on-remote-computers/

Obviously, it implies that the script will do things (i.e read/write operations) on the remote computer instead of yours.
Also, remote connection (in the BIOS settings ?) must be allowed on the remote computer.

Answer (score -1):

You can try installing ssh server where the scripts is located then connect using putty for windows  
then execute refer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119894/single-command-to-login-to-ssh-and-run-program)

Comment: Thank you Bevin NIno. ComputerNameA is actually a server I am not allow to install anything. Even SSH is available in ComupterNameA, I think I cannot use SSH because that will require supply of user name and password in the script.

Comment: if you dont want to include username and pass use certificate

Comment: Thank you Bevin NIno. I ended up trying to use -credential